# In XCode, is there a way to automatically indent lines when I complete a block

Tags: xcode, formatting, indentation, autoformatting

I thought I had this before, but I must've changed a setting or something...

But say I have some code,

```
number = 1
number2 = 2
```

but now I want an if statement to wrap it

```
if(flag)
{
number = 1
number2 = 2
```

After I place the "}", is there a setting that will automatically indent those 2 lines in the block?

```
if(flag)
{
  number = 1
  number2 = 2
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally add the if statement, type `{` at the end of the line, hit return. This produces the block with the closing `}`. Then I cut-paste the code into this block - it will be indented automatically.

You can also select the code and hit `cmd`-`]` to shift it to the right.

Comment: yeah that's what I'm doing now, but I feel like in some other IDE I've used there was the ability to just add the } and it would just automatically indent the block.  I couldn't find the setting, nor could I figure the best way to phrase a google search :\